# Python Pandas: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Tags: python, json, pandas, postgresql, time

I get this error when I run the following codes:

> ```
> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
> ```

There are 9000 records in txt file. Could it be because there are too many records?

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import psycopg2
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
import json
import time
import io

start_time = time.time()
while True:
    temp = pd.DataFrame()
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    with open("vehicle_all_bus.txt", encoding="utf-8") as file:

        fileList = [line.strip() for line in file]
    for ids in fileList:

        r = rq.get('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Vehicle/' + ids + '/Arrivals')
        r = r.text
        temp = pd.read_json(r)
        temp['Type'] = 'ids'
        df = pd.concat([df, temp], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:3434@127.0.0.1/postgres')
    df['timing'] = list(map(lambda x: json.dumps(x), df['timing']))
    df.to_sql('tfl_all_bus_data2', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)


time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Probably `pandas` does not like you `json`. Pandas expects the value to be a list or dict, could you paste an excerpt? Or try this `pd.read_json('r', typ='series')`

Comment: _Could it be because there are too many records?_ Probably not. Please share the entire error message, as well as a proper [mcve].

Comment: Please show sample of `json`. There is  good chance you do not need `pandas` which should be used for data analysis not ETL migrations.